# Upgrade form 16.04 to 18.04 libvirt ssh no longer working?

Tags: ssh, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

After an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 we can no longer ssh into libvirt guests from the host. 'ssh vm-web' just fails silently whereas it worked perfectly before the upgrade. The guests are running as shown by 'virsh list' and I can log into them from virt-manager.

```
xxxxx@yyyy:~$ ssh -v vm-web
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/xxxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/xxxx/.ssh/config line 29: Applying options for vm-web
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.122.101 [192.168.122.101] port 2291.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.122.101 port 2291: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.101 port 2291: Connection timed out
```

This was discovered while trying to solve another problem. The webserver, vm-web, is no longer responding to requests, they just time out.

Comment: Your question should include the *exact and complete* error message that your ssh client gives you. "It fails" is too vague.

Comment: No error message <frown>, it just hangs.

Comment: Use the debug flag to get more output.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was caused by the base address for the  guests being changed from 192.168.122.1 to 192.168.123.1.

```
virsh net-edit default
```

change the three 123s to 122s, reboot and all is good again.

Seems crazy that the addresses should be changed without asking as so much depends on them, but there it is.

Comment: Indeed it should only change on a new installl without former config (e.g. if you first install libvirt and there already is a 192.168.122.x network around blocking the use of that). If you happen to be able to reproduce that "net config changes on upgrade" in e.g. a fresh system could you file a bug about it please?